# How use function from dll in Java

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I know how use native function in Java with my own dll, but what to do if it is not my dll?

For example:

```
package com.example.javaprx08.model;

public class PRx08 {
    static {
        try {
            System.load("C:\\Windows\\System32\\PRx08.dll");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public native short Enumerate();
}
```

I try to do this:

```
PRx08 pRx08 = new PRx08();
        pRx08.Enumerate();
```

but get: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'short com.example.javaprx08.model.PRx08.Enumerate()'

Comment: Does this DLL come with a header file that describes the available functions?

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own dll as wrapper over the "C:\Windows\System32\PRx08.dll" as reference to the project.

This video will explain how to reference a c# dll into the c++ and call it in java. [JNI - Java to C++ and C#](https://youtu.be/tI0tFUjeffA)

You can add reference to any external dll and create a function wrapper to it and call it from java.